# Circular Queue Structure ( array-backed)

Tags: python, queue

I need some help in writing a python program that will implement a circular queue data structure (array-backed). I've completed a few of the methods already but I'm a bit stumped when it comes to adding and taking things away from the queue, as well as checking the values within it. I believe this is of the first-in-first-out structure. Here's what I have for the body so far

```
class Queue:
    ''' Constructor '''
    def __init__(self, limit):
        self.limit = limit
        self.data = [None] * limit
        self.queue = []
        self.head = -1
        self.tail = -1
        self.count = 0


    def dequeue(self):
        if self.count == 0:
            raise RuntimeError
        else:
            self.head = 0
            x = self.queue.pop(0)
            if self.head == self.tail:
                self.head = -1
                self.tail = -1
            else:
                self.tail -= 1
            self.count -= 1
            #self.head += 1
            return x

    def enqueue(self, item):
        if self.count == self.limit:
            raise RuntimeError
        else:
            self.count += 1
            self.queue.append(item)
            self.tail += 1

    def __str__(self):
        return " ".join([str(v) for v in self.queue])


    def resize(self, new_limit):
        new_q = [None]*self.limit
        old_q = self.queue
        for i in range(len(old_q)):
            new_q[i] = old_q[i]
        self.limit = new_limit
        self.queue = new_q


    def empty(self):
        return 0 == self.count

    def iter(self):
        listt = []
        for v in self.queue:
            listt.append(v)
        return listt
```

What I 've written thus far makes the most sense to me but if I were to test this with the following code block I'd get an error saying 10 != 4. This code will fail the 9th line of the test, `tc.assertEqual(q.data.count(None), 4)` I'm unsure why my code is producing the value 10 at this time. What would allow for this class to pass the given test?

```
from unittest import TestCase
tc = TestCase()

q = Queue(10)

for i in range(6):
    q.enqueue(i)

tc.assertEqual(q.data.count(None), 4)

for i in range(5):
    q.dequeue()

tc.assertFalse(q.empty())
tc.assertEqual(q.data.count(None), 9)
tc.assertEqual(q.head, q.tail)
tc.assertEqual(q.head, 5)

for i in range(9):
    q.enqueue(i)

with tc.assertRaises(RuntimeError):
    q.enqueue(10)

for x, y in zip(q, [5] + list(range(9))):
    tc.assertEqual(x, y)
```

Comment: Why not using an existing container such as collections.deque ?

Comment: ... adding to this: Sample SO Q&A for illustration: [efficient circular buffer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151320/efficient-circular-buffer) ... but if you need to write one yourself, I suggest the answer of @Blckknght ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that all the code using `self.queue` is wrong. That attribute isn't needed at all. The whole point of the `data` attribute is to use it to store the values. Use the indexes `head` and `tail` to figure out where in `data` to put things (and where to take them from):

```
class Queue:
    ''' Constructor '''
    def __init__(self, limit):
        self.limit = limit
        self.data = [None] * limit
        self.head = 0
        self.tail = -1
        self.count = 0

    def dequeue(self):
        if self.count == 0:
            raise RuntimeError
        else:
            x = self.data[self.head]
            self.head = (self.head + 1) % self.limit
            self.count -= 1
            return x

    def enqueue(self, item):
        if self.count == self.limit:
            raise RuntimeError
        else:
            self.count += 1
            self.tail = (self.tail + 1) % self.limit
            self.data[self.tail] = item

    def __str__(self):
        return " ".join([str(v) for v in self]) # use __iter__

    def resize(self, new_limit):
        if new_limit < self.count:
            raise RuntimeError
        new_data = [None]*new_limit
        for i, item in enumerate(self):
            new_data[i] = item
        self.data = new_data
        self.head = 0
        self.tail = self.count - 1

    def empty(self):
        return 0 == self.count

    def __bool__(self): # this is better than empty()
        return self.count != 0

    def __iter__(self): # renamed from iter so you can use it in a for loop
        for i in range(self.count):
            return self.data[(self.head + i) % self.limit]
```

You should probably also have a `__len__` method.

Comment: Okay this is starting to make more sense, I just had the head and tail initialized to -1 because the list was empty and that's how I'm being told to represent these attributes when the queue is emptied

Comment: Oh, actually I may be getting things wrong on empty queues. I was thinking it would just work like normal, but you may need `self.tail` to be less than self.head` for it to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd get an error stating that the Queue class doesn't have a data attribute

I don't have the error you mention when running your test on your code.

Comment: I ran it again and that went away, I've updated the actual error I'm getting

Answer (score 0):

If for some reasons you don't want to use built-in [collections.deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) module, here is an example of how you can implement your own circular buffer:

```
"""
Example of circular buffer using regular list
"""


class CircularBuffer:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.buffer = [None] * size
        self.size = size
        self.count = 0
        self.tail = 0
        self.head = 0

    @property
    def is_empty(self):
        return self.count == 0

    @property
    def is_full(self):
        return self.count == self.size

    def __len__(self):
        return self.count

    def add(self, value):
        # if buffer is full overwrite the value
        if self.is_full:
            self.tail = (self.tail + 1) % self.size
        else:
            self.count += 1
        self.buffer[self.head] = value
        self.head = (self.head + 1) % self.size

    def remove(self):
        if self.count == 0:
            raise Exception("Circular Buffer is empty")
        value = self.buffer[self.tail]
        self.tail = (self.tail + 1) % self.size
        self.count -= 1
        return value

    def __iter__(self):
        index = self.tail
        counter = self.count
        while counter > 0:
            yield self.buffer[index]
            index = (index + 1) % self.size
            counter -= 1

    def __repr__(self):
        return "[]" if self.is_empty else "[" + ",".join(str(i) for i in self) + "]"
```