# insert data to numpy array with shift and clip

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an numpy array:

```
x = np.zeros(5)
[0,0,0,0,0]

x.put(5)
[0,0,0,0,5]

x.put([1,2,3])
[0,5,1,2,3]

x.put([5,10,10])
[2,3,5,10,10]
```

I want as shown in the example above. simply I put information at the end. and the data shift and clip the overflow.

Comment: Any reason you need to use a numpy array instead of a [deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque)?

Comment: You can create your own object by inheriting from numpy array and just add a custom append method. Here is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151320/efficient-circular-buffer

Comment: @kennytm yes. because in the end I need a numpy array and this function is executed at least 1 to 2 M times and converting to numpy arrays take considerable computation time

Comment: Note that there exists a function [`ndarray.put`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.put.html), but it does not have the functionality described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy the tail part of the array to the initial part. Note that this method is O(n), so it is not suitable if the array `x` is very long.

```
def push(x, y):
    push_len = len(y)
    assert len(x) >= push_len
    x[:-push_len] = x[push_len:]
    x[-push_len:] = y
    return x
```

```
>>> x = numpy.zeros(5)
>>> x
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
>>> push(x, [5])
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  5.])
>>> push(x, [1,2,3])
array([ 0.,  5.,  1.,  2.,  3.])
>>> push(x, [5,10,10])
array([  2.,   3.,   5.,  10.,  10.])
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the first n values and then roll the array.

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [6, 7, 8]
indexes = range(0, len(y))
np.put(x, indexes, y)
x
[6, 7, 8, 3, 4, 5]
x = x.roll(len(x) - len(y))
x
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```