# Live matplotlib plotting maintaining the axes values (only 10 in x axis)

Tags: python, json, matplotlib, live-streaming

I want to plot a real-time graph in `matplot` lib with a limited number of X axis values (say 10).

My current graph does not do that and instead compresses the entire graph. When i get my 11th value,  I want my 1st value to be wiped off. any ideas? I was thinking of using a cyclic queue, but do not know where and how to start.

My current code (dummy data) is:

```
for i in range(0,100):  #time
    time.sleep(0.1)
    for s in range(0,sensors):
        x[s].append(random.randint(20,80))
    drawnow(makePlot)
```

Comment: Have you tried to adapt any of the methods you can find in [matplotlibs animation examples](https://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/index.html)?

Comment: A [circular buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151320/efficient-circular-buffer) may be a good data structure to consider for your problem.