# efficiency of Hadamard on list of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

The numpy, a Hadmard product on a vertical stack of 1D arrays is significantly faster than looping through the list of 1D arrays and performing the Hadamard (element-wise) product on each (which makes sense, and I tested it anyways).

I have a situation in which I need to perform the Hadamard product between one set of numpy arrays and another as such:

```
stacked_arrays = np.vstack([1D-arrays...])
stacked_arrays *= np.power(factor, np.arange(1, num_arrays))
```

However, *I need this operation to mutate each component 1D array in list*, and this operation needs to happen a lot. I know this sounds like a weird feature, but is there any way to do this without a loop like:

```
factors = factor ** np.arange(1, num_arrays)
for array, f in zip([1D..arrays], factors):
     array *= f
```

or without unstacking the result of the operation?

Also `map` can't be used since `map` creates copies of the numpy arrays as such:

```
result = map(lambda x, y: x * y, zip([1D..arrays], factors))
```

since you can't do `*=` with `lambda` a list of numpy arrays is returned leaving the originals unmutated.

Is there a way to get `np.vstack` to still reference the old component arrays somehow, or an alternative way to achieve the speed of the Hadamard product between arrays that are `stacked` while mutating the unstacked ones? Since some time can be saved if unstacking (`np.split`) doesn't need to occur.

TimeIt results:

```
m = []
for _ in range(100):
    m.append(np.array([1, 2, 4, 5], dtype=np.float64))
factors = np.expand_dims(np.power(2, np.arange(100, dtype=np.float64)), axis=1)

def split_and_unstack():
    l = np.vstack(m)
    l *= factors
    result = np.split(l, 100)

def split_only():
    l = np.vstack(m)
    l *= factors

print(timeit.timeit(split_and_unstack, number=10000))
# 1.8569015570101328

print(timeit.timeit(split_only, number=10000))
# 0.9328480050317012

# makes sense that with unstacking it is about double the time
```

Clarification:
    The list of [1D arrays] mentioned above is  a sublist of a larger list of 1D arrays.
    This larger list is a `collections.deque`. And this `deque` needs
    to be shuffled before  the sublist is extracted (i.e this is an Experience Replay Buffer for Stochastic Gradient Descent).

**Buffer `pop` and `append` speed:**

```
times = int(1e4)
tgt = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])

queue = collections.deque([tgt] * times, maxlen=times)
reg_list = [tgt] * times
numpy_list = np.array([tgt] * times)

def pop():
    queue.pop()
def pop_list():
    reg_list.pop()
def pop_np():
    global numpy_list
    numpy_list = numpy_list[1:]

print(timeit.timeit(pop, number=times))
# 0.0008135469979606569
print(timeit.timeit(pop_list, number=times))
# 0.000994370027910918
print(timeit.timeit(pop_np, number=times))
# 0.0016436030273325741

def push():
    queue.append(tgt)
def push_list():
    reg_list.append(tgt)
numpy_list = np.array([tgt] * 1)
def push_np():
    numpy_list[0] = tgt

print(timeit.timeit(push, number=times))
# 0.0008797429618425667
print(timeit.timeit(push_list, number=times))
# 0.00097957398975268
print(timeit.timeit(push_np, number=times))
# 0.003331452957354486
```

Comment: What is stopping you from indexing the 2D stacked array as if it was a list?

Comment: "since you can't do *= with lambda": Instead of `lambda x, y: x * y` (which could just be `np.multiply`), try `lambda x, y: np.multiply(x, y, out=x)`. Remember, `*=` returns `self` for reassignment just as `*` does.

Comment: @MadPhysicist see my clarification for your first comment. But basing off what you said. I guess the I would keep it as a 2D stacked array, shuffle with `np.random.shuffle` and to make it act as a `deque` do  `2DArray=2DArray[-min(2Darray.shape[0]:, DEQUE_SIZE):, :]` after each time a new row is appended.

Comment: Do you strictly need a deque? Do you know how many rows you will end up with in the end?

Comment: Thing is, you don't need to shuffle the deque, just the indices into it.

Comment: Well I need a deque since it can be an undefined number of rows (an increasing number of rows until program decides to terminate based on a condition), but only a fixed set of rows should be kept at any given time and rows should be discarded after `N` new rows.

Comment: In that case, my solution works perfectly. You just need to maintain a fixed size rotating buffer of size N.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some details you may find interesting/relevant. I'm going to leave the circular buffer implementation up to you. Let me know if you post any related questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break the problem down. You want to have a list of references to arrays that are all mutable, but you want to be able to perform operations on them as a block.

I would maintain that your approach is backwards. Rather than trying to pack and unpack your arrays into separate buffers, maintain views into a single buffer.

Replace your current loop

```
m = [np.array([1, 2, 4, 5], dtype=np.float64) for _ in range(100)]
```

with a single buffer, and views into each row:

```
buf = np.vstack([np.array([1, 2, 4, 5], dtype=np.float64) for _ in range(100)])
m = list(buf)  # check that m[0].base is b
```

Now you have a list of arrays `m`, each of which you can modify individually. As long as you keep the modifications in-place and don't reassign list elements, all the changes will appear directly in `buf`. At the same time, you can perform your batch calculations on `buf`, and as long as you do them in-place, `m` will reflect all the changes.

Realistically, you may not even need `m`. Notice how `list(buf)` creates views into each row of the chunk. You can just as easily index directly into the buffer.  For example, `m[3][8]` would usually be written in terms of `buf` as `buf[3, 8]`, but you can also use the fact that `buf` is a sequence and write `buf[3][8]`. This is less efficient, since it will create a new view (`buf[3]`) every time, but not by much.

To extract a shuffled subset of the rows, you can use sequence indexing as well. Let's say your buffer retains the last `M` rows, which you want to shuffle and extract a subsequence of `N` rows from. You can do this by creating an array of indices, and shuffling those over and over:

```
 indices = np.arange(M)

 # inside the loop:

 np.random.shuffle(indices)
 chunk = buf[indices[:N]]
 # do your math on `chunk`
```

You don't need to reallocate or re-sort `indices` as long as `M` doesn't change and you believe that the shuffle is sufficiently random.

Comment: So one thing I realized regarding the circular buffer, turning the 2D array into a circular buffer sacrifices the [efficiency of deque](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/1wehgw/pythons_deque_is_the_stack_object_you_want_to_use/). I've seen some implementations of creating a Numpy circular buffer and [its efficiency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49800160/4234140). I did some tests (above) comparing pop and append for list, deque and np.array (really setitem since it's a circular buffer), and list and deque don't differ much, but np.array is slow.

Comment: update: so I did find another implementation of the circular buffer using numpy which claims it is faster than `deque` : https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/blob/master/16_reinforcement_learning.ipynb at notebook entry 63.

Comment: @dylan. Why are you using append or insert? The block you have is already a circular buffer. You just have to keep track of which row you are writing to and have a flag that triggers once the buffer is full. It's much more efficient than a deque at that point.

Comment: @dylan. Since the original question wasn't really clear about your purpose, I recommend that you ask another one, showing your research, regarding how to maintain the buffer. There's a lot of scope creep already going on here.