# __getitem__: unsupported operand type(s) for +:'slice' and 'int'

Tags: python-3.x, class-method, operands

I am using a cirularbuffer implementation from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40784706/6754957). Most of the time it works ok. After 4 days running, it result in the following error.

```
File ..., line ... in __getitem__
    return(self._data[(key+self.index) % self.size])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +:'slice' and 'int'
```

The code in question is from above link:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    """Get element by index, relative to the current index"""
    if len(self._data) == self.size:
        return(self._data[(key + self.index) % self.size])
    else:
        return(self._data[key])
```

I am not sure what exactly the error means. Could anyone shed some light?

---

The self._data is the internal list of that circular buffer class. The list content is assinged with the following code (cbuffer::CircularList):

```
if isinstance(rr, rrm.ReadHoldingRegistersResponse):
    self.cbuffer.append([ts, (bw_task.sta, bw_task.start, bw_task.length), rr.registers])
```

The related code that caused the error looks is as below:

```
block_buffer = list(block_buffer)
if len(block_buffer) > 0:
    table_data = self.process_rawdata_block(block_buffer, bw_task)
    # do db operation
    if len(table_data) > 0:
        self.save_to_db(table_data)
    else:
        print("DataMgr.loop.save_to_db: WARNING: empty table_data:", 
        "table_data=", table_data, "while block_buffer=", block_buffer, 
        "bw_task=", bw_task, "wkr.cbuff.length=", len(wkr.cbuffer))
else:
    print("wkr.cbuff.length=", len(wkr.cbuffer))
    if len(wkr.cbuffer) > 0:
        print("wkr.cbuff=", wkr.cbuffer[0:10])  # <---- Throw error in cbuffer.__getitem__()
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, I have no understanding of the **getitem** method, this answer explained it with examples: [Python: Implementing slicing in __getitem__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936863/python-implementing-slicing-in-getitem)

The fix is also simple:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    """Get element by index, relative to the current index"""
    if len(self._data) == self.size:
        if isinstance(key, slice):
            return(self._data[(idx + self.index) % self.size] for idx in range(*key.indices(len(self._data))))
        return(self._data[(key + self.index) % self.size])
    else:
        if isinstance(key, slice):
            return(self._data[idx] for idx in range(*key.indices(len(self._data))))
        return(self._data[key])
```