# npm-hosted libraries for circular/ring buffers

Tags: javascript, data-structures, node.js, npm

Are there any implementations of circular buffers/ring buffers on NPM (Node.JS Package Manager)? I can easily [implement one by myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583123/circular-buffer-in-javascript), but I'd like to have an easily deployable and maintained library.

My use case is storing time series in a fixed-size in-memory database a la RRDTool, but neither RRDTool nor its reimplementation in Javascript (I forgot the name) fit. I need to store large (50KB) JSON objects.

Comment: What's your usecase? (just interested)

Comment: Also, this is an opportunity for you to get nearer to this list: http://npmtop.nodejitsu.com/ :P

Comment: I' rather work on getting https://github.com/socketstream/socketstream or https://github.com/kayuri/HNC closer to production :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realize this was asked almost 4 months ago, but figured I might as well share.

Wrote one myself for another purpose a little while ago and threw it on npm today. It's named [CBuffer](https://github.com/trevnorris/cbuffer). The README.md file has a link to a blog post about how to use it. Just install it by

```
npm install CBuffer
```

And use it in your scripts by:

```
var CBuffer = require( 'CBuffer' ).CBuffer;
```

I've spent a lot of time trying to get GC down to a minimum, and it's the quickest implementation I've been able to find.

Comment: Cool. Is your implementation online? I always like to glean anything I can from other's source.