# Attempt at Circular Buffer - Javascript

Tags: circular-buffer

Right! Here is my attempt at a circular buffer (For use in a graphing program, using the canvas element). Have yet to get round to testing it out.

Question is - Can anyone see any flaws in my logic? Or bottlenecks?

```
/**
*   A circular buffer class.
*   @To add value -> bufferObject.addValue(xValue, yValue);
*   @To get the First-in value use -> bufferObject.getValue(0);
*   @To get the Last-in value use -> bufferObject.getValue(bufferObject.length);
**/

var circularBuffer = function (bufferSize) {

    this.bufferSize = bufferSize;
    this.buffer = new Array(this.bufferSize); // After testing on jPerf -> 2 x 1D array seems fastest solution.

    this.end = 0;
    this.start = 0;

    // Adds values to array in circular.
    this.addValue = function(xValue, yValue) {
        this.buffer[this.end] = {x : xValue, y: yValue};
        if (this.end != this.bufferSize) this.end++;
        else this.end = 0;
        if(this.end == this.start) this.start ++;
    };

    // Returns a value from the buffer
    this.getValue = function(index) {

        var i = index+this.start;

        if(i >= this.bufferSize) i -= this.bufferSize; //Check here.

        return this.buffer[i]
    };

    // Returns the length of the buffer
    this.getLength = function() {
        if(this.start > this.end || this.start == this.bufferSize) {
            return this.xBuffer.length;
        } else {
            return this.end - this.start;
        }
    };

    // Returns true if the buffer has been initialized.
    this.isInitialized = function() {
        if(this.end != this.start) return true;
        else return false;
    };
}
```

Please feel free to reuse this code.

Updated twice (and tested!).

Comment: Yes, the index into the buffer is calculated too often in this.getValue. x and y pairs run together so you should be able to get *point = this.buffer[index]; y = point.y x=point.x*  or similar.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Not sure if I understand it wholly yet. Might make more sense to me after this coffee.

Comment: Got it. Do you mean adding a variable like... [convertIndex = index+this.start;] and then reusing that. If so, done. Thanks!

Comment: My sexy rewrite -> [ this.getValue = function(index) {
  
  var i = index+this.start;
  
  if(i >= this.bufferSize) i -= this.bufferSize; 
  
  return {
   x : this.xBuffer[i],
   y : this.yBuffer[i], 
  };
 };]

Comment: Thats a start :-), but I think you can also merge xBuffer and yBuffer into simply buffer. It's also best to edit your original question as you make changes and just simply note you've updated it

Comment: I've edited your question to show the suggested changes - you'll see it if approved

Comment: Ill update my post in abit. [link](http://jsperf.com/multiple-1d-arrays-vs-object) This jsperf seemed to suggest it was upto 50% faster to use 2 x 1D arrays instead of 1 x 1D array full of objects. Thats the reason I didn't merge the 2 arrays. Would you agree?

Comment: Accepted your edit. Thats really nice. Realised my jsperf was wrong so updated. About similar times now. [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/multiple-1d-arrays-vs-object) Thanks so much for your help dude

Comment: I've always tried to minimize accessing arrays through an index as when I used to work on embedded systems this could account for 20-30% performance loss... processors and compilers have improved since then but I can't shake off my prejudices :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Found another implementation [Circular buffer in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583123/circular-buffer-in-javascript)

Made class variables private, corrected old xBuffer reference. Will do more edits tonight.

```js
/**
*   A circular buffer class.
*   @To add value -> bufferObject.addValue(xValue, yValue);
*   @To get the First-in value use -> bufferObject.getValue(0);
*   @To get the Last-in value use -> bufferObject.getValue(bufferObject.length);
**/

var circularBuffer = function (buffer_size) {

    var bufferSize = buffer_size;
    var buffer = new Array(bufferSize); // After testing on jPerf -> 2 x 1D array seems fastest solution.

    var end = 0;
    var start = 0;

    // Adds values to array in circular.
    this.addValue = function(xValue, yValue) {
        buffer[end] = {x : xValue, y: yValue};
        if (end != bufferSize) end++;
        else end = 0;
        if(end == start) start++;
    };

    // Returns a value from the buffer
    this.getValue = function(index) {

        var i = index+start;

        if(i >= bufferSize) i -= bufferSize; //Check here.

        return buffer[i];
    };

    // Returns the length of the buffer
    this.getLength = function() {
        if(start > end || start == bufferSize) {
            return buffer.length;
        } else {
            return end - start;
        }
    };

    // Returns true if the buffer has been initialized.
    this.isInitialized = function() {
        return (end != start) ? true : false;
    };
}
```

Comment: You've been brilliant dude. Thanks. Don't worry about doing anymore (Unless its for personal achievement :D). Looks beautiful!

Comment: I tend to polish my answers whenever I browse Stackoverflow on other issues :-)

Comment: Suggest you look at the link - this version probably works but the earlier solutions may be more elegant. In particular, pushing and popping may remove the need for complex index calculations

Answer (score 0):

I implemented Vogomatix's code above, and got a few bugs.  The code writes off the end of the buffer, expanding the buffer size automatically, and the addValue function is bound to a particular type.  I've adjusted the code to work with any object type, added some private subroutines to simplify, and added a function to dump the contents out to a string, with an optional delimiter.  Also used a namespace.

What's missing is a removeValue() but it would be just a check of count to be greater than zero, then a call to _pop().

This was done because I needed a rolling, scrolling text buffer for inbound messages, that did not grow indefinitely.  I use the object with a textarea, so I get behaviour like a console window, a scrolling text box that does not chew up memory indefinitely.

This has been tested with expediency in mind, in that I am coding quickly, posted here in the hope that fellow OverFlow-ers use and anneal the code.

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// STYLE DECLARATION
// Use double quotes in JavaScript


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Global Namespace for this application
//

var nz = nz || {};
nz.cbuffer = new Object();


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CIRCULAR BUFFER
//

// CREDIT: 
// Based on...
// Vogomatix http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20119513/attempt-at-circular-buffer-javascript
// But re-written after finding some undocumented features...
/**
*   A circular buffer class, storing any type of Javascript object.
*   To add value -> bufferObject.addValue(obj);
*   To get the First-in value use -> bufferObject.getValue(0);
*   To get the Last-in value use -> bufferObject.getValue(bufferObject.length);
*   To dump to string use -> bufferObject.streamToString(sOptionalDelimiter); // Defaults to "\r\n"
**/

nz.cbuffer.circularBuffer = function (buffer_size) {

    var bufferSize = buffer_size > 0 ? buffer_size : 1; // At worst, make an array of size 1
    var buffer = new Array(bufferSize);

    var end = 0; // Index of last element.
    var start = 0; // Index of first element.
    var count = 0; // Count of elements

    // 'Private' function to push object onto buffer.
    this._push = function (obj) {
        buffer[end] = obj; // Write
        end++; // Advance        
        if (end == bufferSize) {
            end = 0; // Wrap if illegal
        }
        count++;
    }

    // 'Private' function to pop object from buffer. 
    this._pop = function () {
        var obj = buffer[start];
        start++;
        if (start == bufferSize) {
            start = 0; // Wrap
        }
        count--;
        return obj;
    }

    // Adds values to buffer.
    this.addValue = function (obj) {
        if (count < bufferSize) {
            // Just push
            this._push(obj);
        }
        else {
            // Pop, then push
            this._pop();
            this._push(obj);
        }
    }

    // Returns a value from the buffer.  Index is relative to current notional start.
    this.getValue = function (index) {

        if (index >= count || index < 0) return; // Catch attempt to access illegal index

        var i = index + start;

        if (i >= bufferSize) {
            i -= bufferSize;
        }

        return buffer[i];
    }

    // Returns the length of the buffer.
    this.getLength = function () {
        return count;
    }

    // Returns all items as strings, separated by optional delimiter.
    this.streamToString = function (delim) {

        delim = (typeof delim === "undefined") ? "\r\n" : delim; // Default syntax; Default to CRLF

        var strReturn = "";

        var once = 0;
        var index = 0;
        var read = index + start;
        for (; index < count; ++index) {
            if (once == 1) strReturn += delim.toString();
            strReturn += buffer[read].toString();
            read++;
            if (read >= bufferSize) read = 0;
            once = 1;
        }

        return strReturn;
    }
}
```