# splice first added object in an array when new element is added in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

i am working on splicing the old object ie first added object in an array when new element(object) is added in to it automatically.

### this is the sample code i worked on

```
  var sampleArr = [{"id":4,"hostName":"henry"},
                    {"id":3,"hostName":"jeff"},
                      {"id":2,"hostName":"mark"},
                        {"id":1,"hostName":"holder"}];
```

the above array contains 4 objects when 5 object( {"id":5,"hostName":"punk"}) is added i want to splice first added object ie( {"id":1,"hostName":"holder"}).

### here is what i tried in controller

```
for( var i=0; i<sampleArr.length; i++){
          var index = i;
          if(sampleArr.length > 4){
            sampleArr.splice(index,1,sampleArr[i]);

        } 
        }
```

but it not working as i expected. please any help me to sought out this!

Comment: No need of loop `if (arr.length === 4) { arr[0] = newObj; }`

Comment: `splice` can do many things. Can you show us what output you expect?

Comment: var sampleArr = [{"id":4,"hostName":"henry"},
                    {"id":3,"hostName":"jeff"},
                      {"id":2,"hostName":"mark"},
                        {"id":5,"hostName":"punk"}];

Comment: If you were looking for a more... thorough solution, perhaps consider something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583123/circular-buffer-in-javascript?

Comment: do you want first element to remove or the last one coz' {"id":1,"hostName":"holder"} is last element and {"id":4,"hostName":"henry"} is first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the simple `pop()` to take out the last element and use `push` to add a new element into the array!

```js
var sampleArr = [{
  "id": 4,
  "hostName": "henry"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "hostName": "jeff"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "hostName": "mark"
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "hostName": "holder"
}];



sampleArr.pop()

sampleArr.push({
  "id": 5,
  "hostName": "punk"
})

console.log(sampleArr)
```

Comment: @SukumarDhoni Of course you can. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: can i push like this sampleArr.push(sampleArr[sampleArr[5]]);

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unshift` to add new item in begin of array and use `pop` to remove last item in array. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073673/how-can-i-add-new-array-elements-at-the-beginning-of-an-array-in-javascript?answertab=active#tab-top).

Try this:

```
sampleArr.unshift({"id":5,"hostName":"punk"});
sampleArr.pop();
```

Hope will helps.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/33608379/5195629 for an implementation that wraps this in a function (fairly simple really, but I wanted to include it for completeness).

Answer (score 1):

I think OP is asking for FIFO (first in first out operation) , since I don't understand how `{"id":1,"hostName":"holder"}` could be first element in below array. But here is what I suggest.

```js
Array.prototype.performFIFO = function(element) { this.push(element); this.shift(); return this; } 

var sampleArr = [{"id":4,"hostName":"henry"},
                    {"id":3,"hostName":"jeff"},
                      {"id":2,"hostName":"mark"},
                        {"id":1,"hostName":"holder"}];



sampleArr.performFIFO({"id":5,"hostName":"fifth element"})

console.log(sampleArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sampleArr.splice(sampleArr.length,1,sampleArr[i]);
```